# Creating responsive page with image and content

Tags: html, css

I'm new to front-end I'm facing some problems with positioning stuff around and making it resposnive.

So far this is my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #353535;
}

.header {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Inter', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 700px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #3C6E71;
    border-radius: 25px;

}
.header h1{
   margin:  3px; 
  }

.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.content p{
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Inter', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button {
  background-color: #D9D9D9; 
  border: none;
  color: #D00000;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>We found trip that suits you</h1>
        <h1>Kieve Summer Camp</h1>
        <h1>Nobleboro, USA</h1>    
</div> 
    <div class="content">
       <p>
Located on the shores of Lake Damariscotta in Maine, Kieve has been building boys' character and teaching them wilderness skills since 1926. With a heavy focus on excursions—only half the campers are usually on-site, with the other half exploring during the regular camping trips and half-day adventures—activities also include an extensive ropes course, lacrosse, baseball, woodworking, riflery, fishing, swimming, paddle boarding, windsurfing, sailing, tennis, soccer, and photography. A more traditional camp where each boy has a duty, plus takes part in daily activities such as a flag raising and evening prayer, campers are encouraged to try new activities and widen their comfort zones. A sister camp around the lake—Wavus Camp for Girls—operates under a similar philosophy, teaching bravery, resilience, and a reverence for nature.
        </p>  
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7772721/pexels-photo-7772721.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Italian Trulli">  
 </div>
 <button class="button">Save</button>
 <button class="button">Randomize again</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see how I tried so far, and this is what I want to achieve: https://www.figma.com/file/lqy0NTOiakaxeG5HoJk50f/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1.

I know its basic but whatever I try and somehow I make something work other stuff gets bad and so on.

Comment: What is your quistion?

Comment: You can use the flex layout property of CSS

Comment: Can you guarantee that based on the information you provide this question can still be useful/understandable for anyone in like 5 years? Will you guarantee that Figma link is never going to change or go away?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use css grid to get the image and buttons next to the text.

Also wrap the buttons together with the image in a div (I gave it the class right-col):

```
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  gap: 1em;
}

.right-col {
  justify-self: start;
}
```

You'll probably also want to wrap all your code in a wrapper with a max width and make the header and content 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **Flex**.
I have added the comments for CSS changes. For HTML, you can easily understand from the code below.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #353535;
}

.header {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Inter', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 700px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #3C6E71;
    border-radius: 25px;

}
.header h1{
   margin:  3px; 
  }

.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex; /* added flex */
}

/* added new snippet below */
.content div {
   flex: 1;
   width: 50%;
}

.content img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%; /* modified width */
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.content p{
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Inter', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button {
  background-color: #D9D9D9; 
  border: none;
  color: #D00000;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>We found trip that suits you</h1>
        <h1>Kieve Summer Camp</h1>
        <h1>Nobleboro, USA</h1>    
</div> 
    <div class="content">
    <div>
        <p>
            Located on the shores of Lake Damariscotta in Maine, Kieve has been building boys' character and teaching them wilderness skills since 1926. With a heavy focus on excursions—only half the campers are usually on-site, with the other half exploring during the regular camping trips and half-day adventures—activities also include an extensive ropes course, lacrosse, baseball, woodworking, riflery, fishing, swimming, paddle boarding, windsurfing, sailing, tennis, soccer, and photography. A more traditional camp where each boy has a duty, plus takes part in daily activities such as a flag raising and evening prayer, campers are encouraged to try new activities and widen their comfort zones. A sister camp around the lake—Wavus Camp for Girls—operates under a similar philosophy, teaching bravery, resilience, and a reverence for nature.
        </p>  
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7772721/pexels-photo-7772721.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Italian Trulli">
        <button class="button">Save</button>
        <button class="button">Randomize again</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this is what you wanted. If not, let me know.